# Angular Material Paginator to use database data, not the static counter

Tags: angular, angular-material, paginator, angular-material-paginator

I am learging Angular and actually analysing the Angular Material Paginator, with the [AngularMaterial Course](https://github.com/angular-university/angular-material-course/).

Actually the `mat-paginator` page counter is based on a "static" property of a course `lessonsCount`:

`<mat-paginator [length]="course?.lessonsCount"`

the "database" is:

```
export const COURSES: any = {
    1: {
        id: 1,
        description: "Angular for Beginners",
        iconUrl: 'https://angular-academy.s3.amazonaws.com/thumbnails/a.png',
        courseListIcon: 'https://angular-academy.s3.amazonaws.com/main-logo/m.png',
        longDescription: "Establish ...of Angular",
        category: 'BEGINNER',
        lessonsCount: 10
    }
```

and

```
export const LESSONS = {
    1: {
        id: 1,
        "description": "Angular Tutorial For Beginners - Bu...By Step",
        "duration": "4:17",
        "seqNo": 1,
        courseId: 1
    },
    2: {
        id: 2,
        "description": "Building Your First  Component - Component Composition",
        "duration": "2:07",
        "seqNo": 2,
        courseId: 1
    }
```

is there a way to remove that "hardcoded" `lessonsCount` property from the `course` class and use the number of lessons based on the lessons count from the db via `courseId`, and not from the course property "lessonsCount"?

Answer (score 0):

**Application Code :** https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-api-paginator-value?file=src/app/app.component.ts

- In  `<mat-paginator [length]="course?.lessonsCount"`, the `<mat-paginator>`, `[length]`  can be bind to a property of a model class, like here in your case, its binded to `lessonsCount` property of `course` class.
- Or, can be binded to any `private member variable of the component
  class`, so you can bind that with  a local component variable which
  can be updated from the dataArray length which is fetched from any
  api hit.

In the demo code attached, i have changed to `<mat-paginator [length]="count"`, and this count property is updated from data fetched from an api. That api is called from a button click, and randomly calls an api which returns an array, and the length of the array is assigned to this member variable `count`.

> Please comment if this is not the required scenario for the question.